# pl/sql условный оператор

Tags: plsql

Подскажите пожалуйста что означает MOD(s, 2) = 1 
Буду благодарна за помощь

```
BEGIN
DBMS_OUTPUT.enable;
LOOP
     IF(MOD(s, 2) = 1) THEN
      GOTO LESS;
     END IF;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(TO_CHAR(s)||' is even!');      
    <<LESS>>
    EXIT WHEN (s = 20); 
        s := s + 1;
    END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: Надо иначе делать: `IF(MOD(s, 2) = 0) THEN DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(TO_CHAR(s)||' is even!'); END IF;`

Answer (score 0):

В PLSQL функция `MOD( a, b )` возвращает остаток от деления a на b

То есть в вашем случае остаток от деления s на 2 - проверяют на равенство единице - это поиск нечетных значений.

Так же функция MOD возвращает a, если b=0.

Answer (score 0):

MOD возвращает остаток от целочисленного деления

Например

```
MOD(5,2) = 1 
MOD(4,2) = 0
MOD(3,2) = 1
```